# Push notification - Firebase Control Messaging (FCM) - could not run the app (Default Activity not found)

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-instant-apps

I try to add FCM to my app in order to send push notifications.
But I had a problem.

I do everything according to [Google tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

add to the **project** build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha05'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}
```

add to the **app** build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

but after adding

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
```

and sync the project, I have received the build error -

> Default Activity not found

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZrhl.png)

In case of removing firebase dependencies from gradle, everything is ok and the app is running correctly.
Of course, I have updated everything (SDK, gradle version, etc.)

I'm developing instant app so the project in modulated (app, instantapp, base, feature, etc.).

Does anybody know why that is happening?

Comment: can you follow this 
link and do step wise as mention https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/#0

Comment: can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47909531/you-should-have-at-least-one-active-apk-that-is-mapped-to-site-sample-com-via?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging is not yet supported- [reference document](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/prepare.html#identifying_tested_compatible_libraries)

Default Activity not found, for their case, is because the '**app**' config launch option is set to Default Activity - it should be set to URL
Otherwise, Default Activity option requires an  in the '**app**' module's manifest that has

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```