# You should have at least one active APK that is mapped to site 'sample.com' via a web 'intent-filter'

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Trying to upload instant application but getting this error

> You should have at least one active APK that is mapped to site 'sample.com' via a web 'intent-filter'.

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.InstantSplash"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="default-url"
        android:value="https://sample.com/base-app/salt_one" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter
        android:autoVerify="true"
        tools:targetApi="m">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:host="sample.com" />
        <data android:pathPrefix="/base-app" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Instant App Play Store Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629143/android-instant-app-play-store-errors)

Comment: I saw the " 
Possible duplicate" answer but: "This is because the default URL you specified is not supported by the intent-filters in your Instant App", and why this is not supported??? "You will either need to update the default URL so it points to a supported URL, or add a new intent-filter that supports the default URL." adding a new valid url and is this enough???

Comment: yups last one but that didn't solve my problem @Zoe

Comment: @Jorgesys default  is fine problem  before that i was getting that error but then i change to right domain , after i am getting this error

Comment: @Jasss , can you check this url for more understanding about publish instant app. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7381861

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upload installable APK in alpha, beta or production with same HOST web 'intent-filter'.

Comment: This helped when I wanted to push instant-app to pre-release. But when I tried to release it to production I got the same error. Does the installable apk with the intent-filter need to be in production when the instant app is in production? Right now my installable apk is only in alpha.

Comment: will it work ? no need to deploy .apk in to production ?

Comment: you need to deploy base APK in production. because instant application works with modules(parts) so need core APK in production. @droidev

Comment: got it.. they are saying this in the last moment. I have to deploy one more app release just because of this

Answer (score 0):

You are defining an Intent filter with the scheme and host:

```
<data android:scheme="http" />
<data android:host="sample.com" />
```

so you have to access your deep links with

```
http://sample.com
```

**but this domain must be a valid domain**, and this domain must be of your property because you need to add the `assetlinks.json`

> The website www.example.com publishes a statement list at
>   https://www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json. This is the
>   official name and location for a statement list on a site; statement
>   lists in any other location, or with any other name, are not valid for
>   this site. In our example, the statement list consists of one
>   statement, granting its Android app the permission to open links on
>   its site:
>
> ```
> [{
>   "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
>   "target" : { "namespace": "android_app", "package_name": "com.example.app",
>                "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["hash_of_app_certificate"] }
> }]
> ```

Read more about it:

https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/getting-started#quick-usage-example

Comment: I published and test a statement list. but i m still not able to solve this

Comment: Do you have your .well-known/assetlinks.json file configured in your domain?

Answer (score 0):

Instant apps does not support HTTP. Your default-url should be HTTPS

```
<meta-data
        android:name="default-url"
        android:value="https://sample.com/base-app/salt_one" />
```

Comment: i changed to https with but still its saying  You should have at least one active APK that is mapped to site 'sample.com' via a web 'intent-filter'.

Answer (score 0):

Your app must also define a ***default URL*** for your app. ***Within the same Android manifest*** as your ***entry-point activity***, you **define** the ***default URL*** for your app by adding a  element with a value attribute that provides a valid ***HTTPS*** *URL* that the activity can handle. Further, this **default url must also be part of the** ***CATEGORY_LAUNCHER*** activity's intent filter in the installed app.

The following **code snippet** shows an Android manifest that defines an entry-point activity and default URL for an instant app.

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="http" />
      <data android:scheme="https" />
      <data android:host="example.com" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
      android:name="default-url"
      android:value="https://www.example.com/index.html" />
</activity>
```

**Instant apps does not support HTTP. Your default-url should be HTTPS**

For more details can you check android [AIA documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/prepare.html).

*There is some inappropriate string for error message, can you ensure fix with, **installable APK in alpha, beta or production with*** same HOST web 'intent-filter'.

Comment: i changed default url but its still saying
 You should have at least one active APK that is mapped to site 'sample.com' via a web 'intent-filter'.