# Instant Apps: "You should have at least one active APK that is mapped to site 'sample.com' via a web 'intent-filter' " when pushing to production

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-instant-apps

I'm getting the error message when releasing instant-app to production.

I've read this post here: [You should have at least one active APK that is mapped to site 'sample.com' via a web 'intent-filter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47909531/) and this is a bit more specific.

The answer in the above link states:

> Upload installable APK in alpha, beta or production with same HOST web 
>     'intent-filter'.

I uploaded an installable apk w/ the intent-filter to alpha and that the error message went away when releasing my instant-app to pre-release, but when releasing instant-app to production I'm getting the same error.

> You should have at least one active APK that is mapped to site 'sample.com' via a web 'intent-filter'.

My installable apk with the `default-url` intent-filter was only uploaded to alpha. However, I'm wondering if my installable apk w/ intent-filter needs to be moved to production when I try to push my instant-app to production?

Comment: The reason is because the behavior needs to be the same between the same track level of the installed and instant app. The user would experience a different URL resolving behavior if the user uses the installed-app (without the proper intent-filters) after downloading the instant app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the behavior needs to be the same between the same track level of the installed and instant app. The user would experience a different URL resolving behavior if the user uses the installed-app (without the proper intent-filters) after downloading the instant app.

Comment: I have yet to try it, but will update accepted answer once I can confirm

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the app-link to your activity. Here's one example of what it looks like.

```
        <activity
        android:name=".GoodbyeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_goodbye"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <intent-filter
            android:autoVerify="true"
            android:order="1">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="hello-flavors.instantappsample.com" />
            <data android:pathPrefix="/goodbye" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

You can also use App link assistant tool to generate intent-filters. To open it Select Tools > App Links Assistant. For more details go to https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html

Comment: I do have the app link set-up. When testing the app in development and pre-release everything is working fine. When pushing to production, I'm getting this error. I think it has to do with the `default-url` intent filter not being in the production app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define at least one `default-url` as the entry point to your app. I have defined it inside `<activity>` tag as below.

```
<activity .....>
            <meta-data
                android:name="default-url"
                android:value="https://www.example.com/home" />
</activity>
```