# Cannot release instant app : You should have at least one active APK that is mapped to site 'example.com' via a web 'intent-filter'

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I am getting this error :

> You should have at least one active APK that is mapped to site 'www.example.org' via a web 'intent-filter'

I just realized that I have this in my instant app's manifest:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" android:order="2" >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:host="www.example.org" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:pathPrefix="/welcome" />
</intent-filter>

<meta-data
    android:name="default-url"
    android:value="https://www.example.org/welcome" />
```

But in my APK's manifest:

```
<activity>
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <!-- ... -->
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="app.example.org" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Could the `www/app` prefix difference in the Manifests be the reason of this error? I want to make sure about this before releasing another version of the app.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Without seeing the manifest intent-filters and gradle dependecnies for each module, I can't be sure, but it is likely that none of your feature modules contains an intent-filter that maps to www.example.org or the one that does isn't compiled into the instantapp module.

Comment: Please also see these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47909531/you-should-have-at-least-one-active-apk-that-is-mapped-to-site-sample-com-via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47972791/instant-apps-you-should-have-at-least-one-active-apk-that-is-mapped-to-site-s https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629143/android-instant-app-play-store-errors

Comment: @TWL thank you for your answer. But I find it very strange that I've already released a first version of the instant app, and I have made absolutely no change in the related `gradle` and `Manifest` files since that version... so I really don't understand this error.

Comment: Ok I just got it working by adding `<data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.org" />` to my app Manifest's `intent-filter`. Still don't understand why it did work without it in the first place though.

Comment: That's unexpected, but yes, these intent filters require both http and https. How long ago was your first version released? And did you release this one to a different track than your first one?